# How show interstitial ads by number of clicks (google_mobile_ads)

Tags: flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

I want to show an interstitial ads in 10 clicks. Is there a way to do this? Or how I can show only 1 time at the opening of the app? I'm just trying to find how to use it.

```
 ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Ads"),
          onPressed: () {
            _interstitialAd.show();
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageTwo()));
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a counter in your state somewhere and and call the method to show the ad only when it's a multiple of 10.

```
//A field of your state class
int counter = 0;

//...somewhere in build
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text("Ads"),
  onPressed: () {
    if(counter%10 == 0) {
      _interstitialAd.show();
    }

    counter++;
    Navigator.push(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageTwo()));
  },
),
```

Comment: Thank so much. But i don't understand, i am new programmer. Why you used counter%10==0 what is difference between counter == 10 _interstitialAd.show();

Comment: @regenin Good question! So what you propose will only show the ad **once**. The counter will start out 0, the user will click 10 times, and will only show the ad when the counter is 10. The counter will continue to 11, 12, etc. as they click more and the ad will never be shown again. The `%` operator is the modulo operator. You can think of it as getting the remainder if `counter` were to be divided by `10`. This way, the ad will be shown as the counter counts up to 0, 10, 20, 30, etc. as there will be no remainder when the counter is those values.

Comment: Thank you very much for explain me. If I tried such a method, I wonder if I could achieve the same result:  
if (counter == 10) _interstitialAd.show(); 
counter = 0 } 
counter++;

Comment: @regenin Yes that would be nearly the same, with the only difference being the first time the button is clicked, the ad does not show.

Comment: Thank you again. I learned a new method thanks to you. Have a nice day.